# Pyiqvia Format Question (I don't know what data is what)

Tags: python, formatting

Using pyiqvia for a project I'm doing, but I cant seem to figure out where the pollen count or pollution count is in the output. I know there is an index which shows a small float, but it doesn't match the pollen or pollution indexes I am familiar with. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried looking for the documentation, but I could only find short examples and no official documentation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.